# Uso dell'espressione "tutt'oggi"

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

Ho trovato [questo articolo nell'Enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/tutt-oggi-o-tuttoggi_%28La_grammatica_italiana%29/) che riguarda l'espressione "tutt'oggi". Non riesco a capire però quale sia l'uso di tale espressione. Potreste fare qualche esempio?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Di solito l'espressione è

> a tutt'oggi

e significa (dipendendo un po' dal contesto) "ancora oggi", "finora", "fino a questo momento".

> Ci sono problemi che a tutt'oggi restano ancora irrisolti.
>
> A tutt'oggi nessuno è riuscito a vincere il primo premio.

Comment: Il senso è quello, ma dire che la più diffusa sia "a tutt'oggi" mi sembra che potrebbe essere oggetto di punti di vista differenti.